# Infinite windows message loop

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, message

I have this message loop in my program:

```
while (true) {
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            MessageBox(NULL, L"Quit", L"", 0);
            break;
        }
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    } else {
        Render();
    }
}
```

This loop never ends. It never displays the message box even though main window disappears.
Here is the WndProc code:

```
switch (msg) {

    case WM_CLOSE :
        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY :
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default :
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        break;
}

return 0;
```

Could someone please help me? I am literally pulling my hairs out.

Comment: Have you tried tracing messages with [Spy++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264396(v=vs.60).aspx) or a similar tool?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling `PeekMessage(&msg, window, ...)`.  If `window` isn't `NULL`, you'll never get `WM_QUIT`, because `WM_QUIT` is not associated with a window.

Instead, just call `PeekMessage`/`GetMessage` with a `NULL` `HWND`. `DispatchMessage` will send it to the right `WndProc` as necessary. (In general, [making `GetMessage`/`PeekMessage` filter by `HWND` is a bad idea.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/09/369804.aspx))