# My Win32 application won't exit the main loop

Tags: c, windows, winapi

This is my main loop:

```
    while(TRUE)
    {

    PeekMessage(&msg,hWnd,0,0,PM_REMOVE);
        if (msg.message==WM_QUIT)
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);


    }
```

and this is my callback procedure:

```
 LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg1,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
 {
    switch(msg1)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY  :
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg1,wParam,lParam);
}
```

I found out that when I press Close button  WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN will be returned by the PeekMessage function in the next loop, and no WM_QUIT!

Comment: There was another question about this same problem a couple of weeks ago: [Infinite windows message loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658813/infinite-windows-message-loop)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [correct way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) to do a message loop is

```
BOOL bRet;
MSG msg;
while ((bRet = GetMessage(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0)) != 0)
{ 
    if (bRet == -1)
    {
        // handle the error and possibly exit
    }
    else
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); 
        DispatchMessage(&msg); 
    }
}
```

You can use `PeekMessage` if you really need to... but why are you ignoring the return value?

Also, note that this is **specific** to a window. I believe `PostQuitMessage` is for a *thread*... I don't remember it off the top of my head, but you might need to pass `NULL` instead of `hWnd`.

If you have any other windows, that may hijack their message loop as well -- I don't think it's usually an issue, but it might potentially be one; keep that in mind.

Comment: WOW! Thanks! (Damet garm! :D)  I changed it to Null and it worked!

Comment: The hWnd parameter to `GetMessage` should be `NULL` in the main message loop.

Comment: Do you have documentation on a -1 return from GetMessage (or PeekMessage) signifying an error? I can't find this in the SDK docs. It says only non-zero == message available.

Comment: @PaulKeiste: Did you click my link?

Comment: The question says he/she needed to use PeekMessage, which doesn't return an error value like GetMessage, so the main gist of the answer is a red herring.  The core problem is that the original code specifies a specific window instead of NULL, and WM_QUIT message isn't targeted to a specific window.  (Another possible problem is that WM_CLOSE may not lead to a WM_DESTROY.  I usually explicitly handle WM_CLOSE by calling DestroyWindow.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: You did ask, "but why are you ignoring the return value?".

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Right... because even if the OP fixes "the" problem in his code, the code would still be broken without checking the return value. But I never said it's an *error* like in the case of `GetMessage`... so not sure why you think  it's a red herring.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Extra information in an answer is fine, but it's not a substitute for an answer to the actual question.  Will you at least fix the code sample so that it doesn't repeat the real error (using hWnd instead of NULL)?

Comment: Well if I do that then I'd have to modify some other aspects of the answer too... Which I'd rather not do. But I don't mind the downvote, just wanted to know the reason behind it; thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's some code I found. It should give you something to work with.

```
    // Main message loop:
do
{
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    // Run game code here.
    gTradeApp->ExecuteNextAction();
}
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT);
```

and the WndProc

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND aHWnd, UINT aMessage, WPARAM aWParam, LPARAM aLParam)
{
    switch (aMessage)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        return HandleCommand(aHWnd, aMessage, aWParam, aLParam);

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;

    default:
        return DefWindowProc(aHWnd, aMessage, aWParam, aLParam);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend sticking with this, to ensure errors (-1) returned by GetMessage can be handled properly:

```
while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) {
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}
```

Also, another error is not handling WM_CLOSE properly. Try this instead to make your program actually listen to WM_CLOSE (the close button):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch(Message) {
        case WM_CLOSE: {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd); // this
            break;
        }
        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Well, PeekMessage doesn't block. Don't recommend pegging a CPU core by begging voor messages. Why do you need to actually?

Comment: @Orwell: There's definitely situations where you need to use `PeekMessage`. If you think otherwise, consider why that function exists in the first place...

Comment: @Mehrdad: do you mean game engine loops for example? Waiting for a message in the loop instead of filling framebuffers ASAP isn't the handiest way of rendering. Well, ehm, yes, one needs PeekMessage in that case.