# Process stays open after window is closed

Tags: c, winapi, opengl

I have a problem with using the winapi, or so I'm guessing anyway. When I close the application, the process still stays as a 'ghost'. The window disappears as usual, but the process stays which prevents me from recompiling.. I have to kill it manually from the task manager.

I've no clue which part of the code is wrong, and it's somewhat lengthy, so here's a link to the full code: http://pastebin.com/TmRiCeR4

My guess though, is that it might have something to do with this loop:

```
while(1) {
                if(PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
                        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                                break;
                        }

                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                        DispatchMessage(&msg);
                } else
                        draw();

                Sleep(100);   //crappy way of stopping 10000000000000 loops a second

        }
```

I guess it doesn't properly 'escape' the loop so it never gets to the closewindow() function right after it, but I might be wrong. I partially copied the code from a tutorial, although I did change it, so I don't see what the problem is from the tutorial code. Here's the tutorial I'm talking about (perhaps outdated?): http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/11/opengl-in-a-proper-windows-app-no-glut/

Google didn't give me an answer either. Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using `GetMessage()` and a timer? If you only want to draw 10 frames a second `SetTimer()` is more than adequate.

Comment: I dont' necessarily want to only draw 10 frames a second. I simply made it loop very slowly because it was using 100% of one core on the cpu for no good reason, so I just made it loop 10 times a second until the thing actually works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658813/infinite-windows-message-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown the code that actually posts the quit message, but if it's a simple `PostQuitMessage(0);` then your problem is in your `PeekMessage()` call:

```
 if(PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
```

By supplying a window filter (`hwnd`) you are preventing `PeekMessage()` from retrieving any posted thread messages (that is, messages sent not to a window, but to the thread). Since `PostQuitMessage()` posts a thread message, your loop will never retrieve it and so never exit.

You should change your call to pass `NULL` for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change it so that rather than while(1)

```
int continue = 1;

while(continue > 0)
```

and

```
if(msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
                           continue = 0;
                           break;
                           }
```

I would also shorten the sleep.

Comment: This didn't do anything unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

When a window is closed a `WM_CLOSE` message is generated, which you normally process in the Window Class's message function. The usual reaction is to call `PostQuitMessage` which will send a a `WM_QUIT` message. In your main application loop you test for `WM_QUIT` and when that message arrives, you do all the necessary shutdown and break out of the loop or call `ExitProcess`

If there's *no* idle processing to do, instead of sleeping after a `PeekMessage` you should use `GetMessage`, which sleeps internally until the next message arrives. However an OpenGL animation loop qualifies as idle processing, so you can't do that.

But if your draw call iterates a million times a second you got another problem: Namely you've got no vertical retrace synchronization (V-Sync) enabled in your graphics driver. **Enable it!**

Since we want our programs to be robust, i.e. if they run on a different user's computer where V-Sync is disables as well, it makes sense though, to limit the iteration count to some reasonable number. This shouldn't be done using a hard `Sleep` though. Instead you should measure the time `dT` between `draw()` iterations and if it's less than, say 5ms (i.e. 200Hz) you should add a sleep of `5 - dT - 1` after the draw.

Comment: exitprocess didn't work either.. I'm starting to think it never gets 'past' the if msg.message == quit thing. I tried putting a messagebox instead of a break in to that if, and it never pops up. Perhaps that's just because it closes the window before it can pop up?Also I noticed the code I posted probably doesn't even compile, no clue why because I didn't edit it and it compiled for me. There are 2 breaks outside of a loop and showwindow's second argument should be 10. No clue how I even made that compile but oh well.